# Can't find LaTex font phvb on mac

Tags: fonts, errors, texlive, installing, mactex

I was compiling a latex document on mac osx and getting this error:

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf phvb
! I can't find file `phvb'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvb

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvb

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: phvb.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input phvb' failed to make phvb.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \nipstenhv=phvb at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
l.45 \font\nipstenhv  = phvb at 8pt
```

Where can I get this font for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 5):

The reason this happened was that I had installed just the mactex-basic (Basic-Tex), and that does not install the URW "Base 35" font pack for LaTeX (which includes **helvetic**) package by default.

To fix either run

```
sudo tlmgr install helvetic
```

or install package **helvetic** using the TeX Live Utility from http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/

Comment: Do yourself a favour and install the whole 2.5G byte of MacTeX.  It saves so much grief.

Comment: I was doing a short one-off task for someone, and he just needed to view the output of a single LaTex doc.  Installing 2.5Gb would have been overkill.  It is not an unreasonable assumption that something called **mactex-basic** would contain the common Mac fonts.  But in this case, I was wrong :)

Comment: i ran into the same problem and solved it by using the online LaTeX editor http://sharelatex.com

Comment: If you just installed basicText, you might need to update tlmgr too

`sudo tlmgr update --self`